# An Ampscript loop that will show columns in a foreach instead of rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I don't think this is possible, but has anyone ever created an ampscript loop that went on column data instead of row data in a lookup data extension?

I was thinking of using a **BuildRowsetFromString** with the row names from a primary lookup. I have not tried anything yet, this is my first attempt.

Comment: Yes, you can write table columns in an AMPscript loop. Can you be more specific about your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many cases you could just regularly transform your source table into key / values using SQL, then you can do a normal row-based lookup on the result.

```
SELECT
subscriberKey
,'column1' as key /*this is the column headline (fieldname) */
,column1 as value /* this is the value of the field with the matching name */
FROM table
WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND column1 != ''

UNION 

SELECT
subscriberKey
,'column2' as key 
,column2 as value 
FROM table
WHERE column2 IS NOT NULL AND column2 != ''
/*....*/
```

table looks like this:

```
subscriberKey,key,value

subscriberKey1,column1,valueOfColumn1
subscriberKey1,column2,valueOfColumn2
subscriberKey2,column1,otherValueOfColumn1
subscriberKey2,column2,otherValueOfColumn2
/* etc */
```

Then you can read all rows where row name (now key) was equal to 'column1':

`SET @rowset = LookupRows(@resultTable,"key",'column1')`

etc